# How to format an html script reference to a folder outside of the parents directory

Tags: html, reference

In an html file, I need to reference a script outside of the html's parents directory. Attached is a picture of the directory. I need to make a script reference from layout.html to js/index.js. I've tried:

```
<script src = "{{ url_for('shop', filename = 'index.js') }}"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/../js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/index.js"></script>
```

But none of these works. Please help!
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KcvB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace yours into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: This gives me the same 404 error as my js folder is not in the same directory as the folder containing the html file

Comment: Check out the directory pic again and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @Pambalos try put `~` this before the directory?

Comment: :/ tried that too, but that didn't work for me either. Same 404 not found error

Comment: Strange somehow, with the absolute path, it should works :v

Comment: can you try to debug using your browser? like find the exact path of it? http://...../js/index.js to check whether the correct path?

Comment: Okay, tried a couple of those, but they didnt work, let me see if I cant locate it